# Spring Bean Dynamic List Argument issue

Tags: spring

i am having a class with constructor Long, Long, new ArrayList now i would need to create a spring bean where the constructor values are dynamic. so i would like to create as follows

1. constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Long" value="0" - zero for dummy
2. constructor-arg index="1" type="java.lang.Long" value="0" - zero for dummy
3. constructor-arg index="2" type="java.lang.ArrayList" - ??

not sure about the dummy value to be defined....when i don't give the dummy value field spring initialization throws the error value is required

how to create a spring bean where the list is with/without type safe and pass the values dynamically..

example, getBean("myCountry", long, long, countries list)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually since you plan on using getBean the bean must be declared prototype, which means you don't need to provide any constructor arguments:

```
<bean id="testBean" class="TestBean" scope="prototype"/>
```

You can then just call getBean and it should work. I've tested this on Spring 3.2.11.

Comment: <bean id="testHelper"
          class="com.sample.application.controller.TestHelper"
          scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Long" value="0"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.lang.Long" value="0"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" type="java.util.ArrayList">
            <value></value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>     ... This got worked finally....

Comment: What I mean is you don't need to use <constructor-arg> at all if scope is prototype.